# Edit and Save data to firebase with setDoc()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

Soo I want to save an edited item from an array to firebase but when I try to to with setDoc() I get this error below

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ta2', but it was: a custom Aa2 object
```

This is my code:

```
<div v-for="(post, id) in posts" :key="id">
  <h3>By: {{ post.name }}</h3>
  <p>{{ post.post }}</p>
  <p>{{ post.date }}</p>
    
  <button @click="deletePost(id)">delete</button>
      
  <div v-if="post === postItemToEdit">
    <input type="text" v-model="post.post" >
    <button @click="savePost">Save</button>
    <button @click="cancleEditMode">Cancle</button>
  </div>
      
  <button v-else @click="editPost(post)">Edit</button> 
</div>

<script setup>
  const blogCollectionRef = collection(db, "blogs")

  const name = ref("")
  const post = ref("")
    
  const addPost = () => {
    addDoc(blogCollectionRef, {
      name: name.value,
      post: post.value,
      date: Date.now(),
    });

    name.value = ""
    post.value = ""
  }

  const postItemToEdit = ref()

  const editPost = (post) => {
    postItemToEdit.value = post
  }
  
  const savePost = () => {
    postItemToEdit.value = (false)

    setDoc(blogCollectionRef, {
      post: "Los Angeles"
    })
  }
</script>
```

I think it has to do with the fact that I'm using collection instead of doc but the array I'm fetching is stored in a collection I named "blogs".

Comment: Are you trying to add a document with random ID? If yes, then use `addDoc()` instead. If you want to specify your own ID, then try `setDoc(doc(blogCollectionRef, "doc_id"))...`

Comment: I'm using the id generated from firebase  and I dont want to add another document, I just want to edit and save an existing one.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I can't see where `posts` array is coming from but make sure it contains the document ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `updateDoc()` to update an existing document and not `setDoc()`. You'll need the document ID so you can just pass it to the `savePost()` function:

```
<div v-for="(post, id) in posts" :key="id">
  <!-- ... -->
    <button @click="savePost(post.id)">Save</button>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

```
const savePost = async (postId) => {
  postItemToEdit.value = (false)

  await updateDoc(doc(blogCollectionRef, postId), {
    post: "Los Angeles"
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but I want to bind the new changes from the input to the updateDoc function so that the post won't be "Los Angeles" but the value of the input instead